# Open file using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro on MacOS via Parallels using Excel, the macro has previously been running on a PC using Excel.

When I try to change the path, I'm getting a Compile error and Syntax error as shown below:

```
'...
Dim SaveName As String 
SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Text 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:/Boon (1)/Doggle/2016 Harvest/" & SaveName & "" 
End Sub
```

I've also tried:

```
SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Text 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="/Users/spirulina/Google Drive/Boon (1)/Doggle/2016 Harvest/" & SaveName & "" 
End Sub
```

As well as:

```
Dim SaveName As String 
SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Text 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\Users\spirulina\Google Drive\Boon (1)\Doggle\2016 Harvest\" & SaveName & ""
```

EDIT: Correct syntax was found to be:

```
Workbooks.Open "X:/Boon (1)/Doggle/2016 Harvest/" & SaveName
```

Comment: What is the value of `Application.PathSeparator` ?

Comment: Remove this [ & "" ] after savename

Comment: I removed the &"" after save name. I get the same error: Compile Error Syntax error.

Comment: @Om3rI removed the &"" after save name. I get the same error: Compile Error Syntax error.
The new line looks like this: 
 SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Text
       Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:/Boon (1)/Doggle/2016 Harvest/" &
           SaveName

Comment: @RobinMackenzie
the character used to separate folder names is currently a forward slash (as it appears in my original problem description) although I was trying back slash for a while tool.

Comment: You on mac computer? Which office are you using?

Comment: So my suggesting worked?